# What does "dispatches" files in rails src folder mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just look up at rails sources and find folder named "dispatches". There is four file in it. I want to know purpose of this files. I know I use this files on my production server, but I never used to think of their purpose. I know there is something about attaching Rails app to Apache server. On my production server `rails appname` command add this files to `public` folder automatically. Can I set up this behavior on my development machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rails dispatcher is the entry point for a rails application and is used to bootstrap the environment.

They have a long history and in a lot of ways they are *almost* obsolete.  In days gone by rails apps used to be powered using cgi or fastcgi, which was a way for the webserver to communicate with a rails process.  The boot process would be initiated by `dispatch.fcgi` or `dispatch.cgi`.  Nowadays people are more likely to use `apache/nginx+passenger` or `apache/nginx+mongrel/thin`.  (Does anyone still use lighttpd?)

I'm a little fuzzy on how `dispatch.rb` is used, but I think it's used by upstream rails servers such as mongrel/thin to bootstrap the rails process.  However, now that rails is rack compatible I'm not entirely sure if that has changed.

You don't need to pay the `dispatch.*` files any attention.

I hope this helps.